# Data Contract does not appear in Service reference... How can I add it?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a silverlight application that runs WCF services.

I have created a WCF service on the server side, it has a data contract. I have also added the service reference on the client side.

I now want the client side to be able to access the data from the server side, so when i tried writting serviceReference.dataContract_Name, it didnt work.

The data contract does not appear in the service reference either.

I dont know if this makes sense, can someone identify what it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanna get data contract on client side, you should declare operation contract with this data contract as argument or as return type. Check this in your code, it can be the reason.

Comment: ahhh! OK, thanks!! That is why! Been trying to figure it out the whole morning!!